# Mongodb type reference node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying reference another object in a model in node,

```
User = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            index: {unique: true}
        }
});

Idea = new Schema({
        Creator: {
            type: User
        }
});
```

but I get this error `Undefined type at "creator" Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.` I believe I want to use refs, but could not find documentation on it, can some one help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found out the answer to my own question here it is.

```
User = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: {unique: true}
    }
});

Idea = new Schema({
    Creator: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. life saver 2. what's the difference between `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` and `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId`? I found it really confusing, it triggers "Undefined type" errors and its difficult to understand why

Comment: i want to know the diff of
mongoose.Types.ObjectId VS mongoose.Schema.ObjectId too!

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to add a reply to this question because it's the first result in Google.

No you can't use Nested Schema as the other replies say. But you can still use the same object in different schema.

```
// Regular JS Object (Not a schema)
var Address = {
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    city: String,
    postalcode: String
};

var Customer = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    address: Address
});

var Store = new Schema({
    name: String,
    address: Address
});
```

That way you can modify the Address Object to make the changes available on all your schemas sharing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) to manual @ refs.

Tho You can't use refs at schema design level.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve a similar problem for my project by making my subdocument a nested type

```
    Foo = new Schema({
        name: String,
        bar: {
            name: String
        }
    });
```

Obviously this will not work if you need Bar to be its own model. Perhaps because you reference it as a model in other objects. In my case this was all I needed to do, but the Subdocuments section of the Mongoose guide does not mention it as an option so I am adding to this discussion.